# elements inside @if condition in CSHTML page is not displayed even when the condition is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, if-statement, razor

This is my CSHTML page.

```
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="8">
            <tr>
                <th>File Path</th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.returnFilename, new { id = "filepath" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <table cellpadding="8">
                <tr>
                    <th>File Names</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.getFileNamesList, new SelectList(Model.getFileNamesList, "getFilepath", "getFileNames"), " -- Select File --", htmlAttributes: new { style = "width: 200px;" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            console.log("in script");
            $("[id$=filepath]").on('change', function () {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        url: '/Home/LoadFiles',
                        data: { filePath: $(this).val() }
                    })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

The JavaScript call is made when something is entered in the text box and return. This will call a controller method and fetch the details for a dropdown.

Controller method.

```
 public ActionResult LoadFiles(string filePath, FeatureDisplayListModel getFileName)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            string errorMessage = "";

            GetFilesModel objFileNames = new GetFilesModel();

            try
            {
                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(filePath);

                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {
                    if (getFileName.getFileNamesList == null)
                    {
                        getFileName.getFileNamesList = new List<GetFilesModel>();
                    }

                    string trimFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    objFileNames.getFileNames = trimFileName;
                    objFileNames.getFilepath = fileName;

                    getFileName.getFileNamesList.Add(objFileNames);
                }

                getFileName.isFileName = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "NO TAG FOUND";
                //featAndChannel.returnFilename = featureID + " - " + childFeatureID + " " + errorMessage;
                return View("Index", getFileName);
            }

            return View("ConfigChecker", getFileName);
        }
```

When the details are fetched and returned back to view. The @if condition encapsulating the dropdown is not working. Though it gets into the @if block it is not displaying the dropdown inside it.

Comment: Can you show us `FeatureDisplayListModel` class

Comment: Please see the model class @abdul
```
namespace ConfigChecker.Models
{
    public class FeatureDisplayListModel
    {
        //public List<FeatureDisplayModel> featChannelList { get; set; }

        public List<GetFilesModel> getFileNamesList { get; set; }
        public string returnFilename { get; set; }

        public bool isFileName { get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from action with ajax,you can try to return `List<GetFilesModel>` type data to ajax,and then adding html to dropdown with the data:

action:

```
public List<GetFilesModel> LoadFiles(string filePath, FeatureDisplayListModel getFileName)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            string errorMessage = "";

            GetFilesModel objFileNames = new GetFilesModel();

            try
            {
                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(filePath);

                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {
                    if (getFileName.getFileNamesList == null)
                    {
                        getFileName.getFileNamesList = new List<GetFilesModel>();
                    }

                    string trimFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    objFileNames.getFileNames = trimFileName;
                    objFileNames.getFilepath = fileName;

                    getFileName.getFileNamesList.Add(objFileNames);
                }

                getFileName.isFileName = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "NO TAG FOUND";
                //featAndChannel.returnFilename = featureID + " - " + childFeatureID + " " + errorMessage;
                return getFileName.getFileNamesList ;
            }

            return getFileName.getFileNamesList ;
        }
```

ajax:

```
$(function () {
        console.log("in script");
        $("[id$=filepath]").on('change', function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    url: '/Home/LoadFiles',
                    data: { filePath: $(this).val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#getFileNamesList").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, FileNamesList) {
                         items += "<option value='" + FileNamesList.getFilepath + "' selected>" + FileNamesList.getFileNames + "</option>";

                    });
                    $('#getFileNamesList').html(items);
                    
            },

                
        })
    })
```